# change the title for index column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

cust_no = np.arange(111,555,111)
snapshot = list(range(201809,201813))
income = np.random.randint(50,5000,32)
expense = np.random.randint(10,1000,32)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = list(zip(cust_no, snapshot,income, expense)), 
                  columns = ['cust_no','snapshot',  'income', 'expense'])

df.set_index('snapshot', inplace=True)
df
```

I want to change the title "snapshot" to "start_of_month". I could apply `reset_index()`, change column title and then `set_index()`. But seems like a lot of overkill.

Is there a simpler way ?

Comment: [set name](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.set_names.html) could suffice

Comment: I guess you're looking for `df.index.name = 'start_of_month'`

Comment: @Marat that's is exactly what I needed !!! Thanks !!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer was by @Marat.

`df.index.name = 'start_of_month'`

Answer (score 1):

you can just use this:

```
df.rename(columns = {'snapshot':'start_of_month'}, axis='columns', inplace =True)
print(df.columns)
```